# Select range from A1 to end of file using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select all values in Excel 2007 worksheet between A1 and end of file (effect of ctrl End). There are always 4 columns but the rows will range from 2 to possibly hundreds. There will possibly be lots of blank cells throughout the selection, including the last cell.

The following just goes to the last cell to be selected, not the entire range. How can I modify this to accomplish what I want?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it. The SpecialCells method needs a qualifier:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

Comment: I thought I tried this but obviously had some sort of syntax wrong. Thanks. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the first four columns, then perhaps:

```
Sub dural()
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:D")).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Record a macro doing it then review the code:

Something like this may work.

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

Running this macro selected the below in my example:
[image]